# Scraping issue (data-reactid)

Tags: java, html, automation, web-scraping, imacros

I'm trying to scrape a website and compile a spreadsheet based on what data I pull.
The website I am trying to scrape is [WEARVR](https://www.wearvr.com/).
I am not too experienced with scraping, but my approach would be to find unique attributes within html tags and use this to scrape what I want.
So for this website my approach would be firstly to scrape a list of URLs of the pages you are taken to upon clicking on one of the experiences, for example : https://www.wearvr.com/#game_id=game_1041,
 and then secondly, cycle through this list scraping the relevant attributes each time.
However I am stuck at the first step as instead of working with simple "a href" tags, I come across "data-reactid" tags which confuse the matter.

I do my scraping with iMacros but I'm pretty decent at Java now so would learn scraping in Java if need be (which seems likely as iMacros is pretty limited).

My question is, how do these "data-reactid" tags work, and as such how can I utilise them for my scraping purposes?

Additionally if this is an XY problem, please let me know and suggest a better approach.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to approach scraping is to treat the page like a big string (because ultimately, that is what it is).  You can search within that string for certain things (like href=) to grab links.  You can also intelligently assume that whatever is in the a tags is relevant to the link and grab that.

You really don't have to understand HTML, and you don't have to understand how the page or any additional css or markup work, you just need to identify what sort of identifiable string combinations are around the text you want.  I will say this is probably much easier to implement in Java than using IMacro, and probably more accurate.

The other way you can handle it, which requires a little more knowledge of HTML and XML, is to treat the entire page as an XML document.  This...doesn't always work with HTML, particularly if it is older or badly formed, so the string approach is easier.  You get some utility out of the various XML map libraries that exist, but otherwise its similar to the above.